# inserting multiple checkbox values into a single column - SQL database

Tags: php, checkbox

i want get all values from checkbox and insert it on one column like 1,2,3

that my code , i don't know what's wrong

```
<form method="post" style="display:inline">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="1">1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="2">2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="3">3</label>
</form>

        <?php
if ($_POST['do'] =="insertawards")
{
    $media_array = $_POST['data'];
    $values = array();
    foreach($media_array as $value)
    {
        $values[] = $value;
    }
    $values = implode(',', $values);
        $db->query_write("INSERT INTO " . TABLE_PREFIX . " awards (awards_forumid,awards_userid,awards_name,awards_link) 
        VALUES('".$values."','0','".$_POST['awards_name']."','".$_POST['awards_link']."') ");
}
        ?>
```

when i used implode , i get error and inserting 0 on datbase

```
$media_array = $_POST['data'];
foreach ($media_array as $one_media)
{
$source .= $one_media;
}
$source = implode(',', $source);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the submit button is missing, anyway, if you need to implode the values properly. Consider this example: (i assume 1, 2, 3 are inserted each not the whole string is inserted like 1,2,3)

```
<?php

define('TABLE_PREFIX', 'vb_');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // quick and dirty, just roll up your sanitation
    $media_array = $_POST['data'];
    $awards_name = '"'.$_POST['awards_name'].'"';
    $awards_link = '"'.$_POST['awards_link'].'"';
    $checkbox_values = '"'.implode(',', $media_array).'"';
    $statement = "INSERT INTO ".TABLE_PREFIX."awards (awards_forumid,awards_userid,awards_name,awards_link) ".
        "VALUES ($checkbox_values, '0', $awards_name, $awards_link)";
    echo $statement;
    // INSERT INTO vb_awards (awards_forumid,awards_userid,awards_name,awards_link) VALUES ("1,2,3", '0', "best_website", "http://www.google.com/")
}

?>

<form method="post" style="display:inline">
    <input type="hidden" name="awards_name" value="best_website" />
    <input type="hidden" name="awards_link" value="http://www.google.com/" />
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="1">1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="2">2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="data[]" value="3">3</label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: kevinabelita,thnx brother , but it's not work with me , values on column = 0

Comment: @o6qr wow :) no error whatsoever? my tip is, try to build the query statement first (test the echoed query of `$statement` in phpmyadmin, so that you'll see errors

Comment: :) sorry , i try it agine , show me this error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: @o6qr i updated the answer maybe you forgot `$db->query_write($statement)`

Comment: no i don't forget it , i used it already  [$db->query_write("INSERT INTO ]

Comment: @o6qr this is just an example, i dont know the complete structure of your db as you didn't put it in your question, you will just have to modify the answer (the `$statement`) to fit into your situation

Comment: okay brother , I'll try to discover the error , thnx any way :)

Comment: kevinabelita, that error becouse values inserting like that VALUES(("1"),("2"),("3")); and i have one Column not three Columns .. so there is something wrong in your code .

Comment: @o6qr maybe you could post your full code so that it can be diagnosed :), i cant guess what you already written on your side, just edit the question

Comment: @o6qr and please dont put `()` inside the `$values` variable. I think what you did is: `$statement = "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ($values)";`

Comment: okay i edit the post and put my code , ($values) must be like this becouse i have another values for another columns ..

Comment: i used your edit but only insert first value , not all VALUES

Comment: when i add loop like this `foreach($_POST['data'] as $value){$values .= $value;}` and used var `$value` , add all VALUES but without comma, `12345`

Comment: and if used `implode(',', $values)` show me error and inserting 0 value

Comment: @ kevinabelita , thanx brother i found the problem and i put the Solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

i found what's problem ,

the problem not in code , this will be adding values array on mysql like 1,2,3,4

```
$values = implode(',',$_POST['data'])."\n";
```

the real problem on Type of mysql field , i make it `int(10)` While must be `mediumtext` Even accept coma .

Excuse me and thank for your efforts @user1978142